# Can we use same button to hide/show multiple divs

Tags: javascript, css, function, display

I have 3 anchor tag buttons and 6 divs, i want to assign 2 divs each for a button and when clicked both the assigned divs should get displayed/hidden accordingly.

I was able to hide/show the 1st 3 divs using below code however for next 3 divs(image section) my code is not working

**html:**

```
//button section
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-4 col-sm-2 col-lg-2">
      <div class="mx-2"><a id="me" class="trans-btn selected" onclick="show('id1');">Widget</a></div>
      <div class="mx-2"><a id="me" class="trans-btn" onclick="show('id2');">Widget</a></div>
      <div class="mx-2"><a id="me" class="trans-btn" onclick="show('id3');">Widget</a></div>
   </div>
//1st 3 divs
   <div class="col-8 col-sm-5 col-lg-5">
      <div class="mx-2" id="id1">
         <h3>Tabs with soft transitioning effect.</h3>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod 
            bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor sit amet lacus accumsan et viverra 
            justo commodo. Proin sodales pulvinar tempor. Cum sociis natoque 
            penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes.
         </p>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod 
            bibendum laoreet.
         </p>
         <a class="btn-warning" href="">Download</a>
      </div>
      <div class="mx-2" id="id2" style="display:none;">
         <h3>Tabs Different effect.</h3>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod 
            bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor sit amet lacus accumsan et viverra 
            justo commodo. Proin sodales pulvinar tempor. Cum sociis natoque 
            penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes.
         </p>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod 
            bibendum laoreet.
         </p>
         <a class="btn-warning" href="">Download</a>
      </div>
      <div class="mx-2" id="id3" style="display:none;">
         <h3>Tabs most of effect.</h3>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod 
            bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor sit amet lacus accumsan et viverra 
            justo commodo. Proin sodales pulvinar tempor. Cum sociis natoque 
            penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes.
         </p>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod 
            bibendum laoreet.
         </p>
         <a class="btn-warning" href="">Download</a>
      </div>
   </div>

//next 3 divs(image section)
   <div class="col-12 col-sm-5 col-lg-5 last-sec">
      <div class="mx-2" id="id1"><img class="img-fluid" src="assets/images/shadow-img.png"/></div>
      <div class="mx-2" id="id2" style="display:none;"><img class="img-fluid" src="assets/images/shadow-img.png"/></div>
      <div class="mx-2" id="id3" style="display:none;"><img class="img-fluid" src="assets/images/shadow-img.png"/></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
function show(elementId) { 
    document.getElementById("id1").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("id2").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("id3").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById(elementId).style.display="block";
}
```

Any alternative method to show/hide both the divs when clicked the assigned button?

Comment: You should use generic `class` names for all hide/show divs and jquery `toggle` will do this as per your requirements.

Comment: You have duplicate IDs all over the place, like `<div class="mx-2" id="id1">` and other - ID should be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same `id` twice. This is not allowed. I've changed your HTML to correct this problem. I hope this helps.

```js
function show(elementId) { 
   let divs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[id ^= 'did']"));
   let imgs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[id ^= 'iid']"));
   divs.forEach(d=>{d.style.display="none"})
   imgs.forEach(i=>{i.style.display="none"})
   document.getElementById("d"+elementId).style.display="block";
   document.getElementById("i"+elementId).style.display="block";
    }
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-4 col-sm-2 col-lg-2">
      <div class="mx-2"><a id="me" class="trans-btn selected" onclick="show('id1');">Widget1</a></div>
      <div class="mx-2"><a id="me" class="trans-btn" onclick="show('id2');">Widget2</a></div>
      <div class="mx-2"><a id="me" class="trans-btn" onclick="show('id3');">Widget3</a></div>
   </div>
<!--1st 3 divs-->
   <div class="col-8 col-sm-5 col-lg-5">
      <div class="mx-2" id="did1">
         <h3>Tabs with soft transitioning effect.</h3>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod 
            bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor sit amet lacus accumsan et viverra 
            justo commodo. Proin sodales pulvinar tempor. Cum sociis natoque 
            penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes.
         </p>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod 
            bibendum laoreet.
         </p>
         <a class="btn-warning" href="">Download</a>
      </div>
      <div class="mx-2" id="did2" style="display:none;">
         <h3>Tabs Different effect.</h3>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod 
            bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor sit amet lacus accumsan et viverra 
            justo commodo. Proin sodales pulvinar tempor. Cum sociis natoque 
            penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes.
         </p>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod 
            bibendum laoreet.
         </p>
         <a class="btn-warning" href="">Download</a>
      </div>
      <div class="mx-2" id="did3" style="display:none;">
         <h3>Tabs most of effect.</h3>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod 
            bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor sit amet lacus accumsan et viverra 
            justo commodo. Proin sodales pulvinar tempor. Cum sociis natoque 
            penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes.
         </p>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod 
            bibendum laoreet.
         </p>
         <a class="btn-warning" href="">Download</a>
      </div>
   </div>

<!--next 3 divs(image section)-->
   <div class="col-12 col-sm-5 col-lg-5 last-sec">
      <div class="mx-2" id="iid1"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/pin.png"/></div>
      <div class="mx-2" id="iid2" style="display:none;"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/cat.svg#blackcat"/></div>
      <div class="mx-2" id="iid3" style="display:none;"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/cat.svg#redcat"/></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at including jQuery into your project. jQuery provides this functionality already.

Add this code inside your html tag:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

And then you will be able to utilise the following functions in this case - the toggle function where you can toggle classes of your specified elements:

```
$( "#id1, #id2, #id3" ).toggle(
  function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "show" );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "hide" );
  }
);
```

See the jquery documentation for toggle and click events:

https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

[https://api.jquery.com/click/](https://api.jquery.com)

and generically the jQuery documentation to find other similar functionality:

https://api.jquery.com

If you add bootstrap to your project, the show and hide classes would already be included in your project.. and provide the functionality that you desire.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, but what about the duplicate ids in the original code? Not sure if it will work and it's definitely invalid HTML

Comment: @AlonEitan you'll have to change the id's to classes

Comment: Well it isn't my question, but I think that any answer to this question should say something about the duplicate IDs issue and suggest an alternative and VALID (html-wise) way to solve it: _"I was **able** to hide/show **the 1st** 3 divs using below code however for **next 3 divs** (image section) my code is **not** working"_

Comment: @Alon thanks for your help, now i have removed the duplicate ids from my code and able to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.querySelectorAll` method and hide all this elements

```js
function show(elementId) { 
    [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".myBlock"),0).map(e=>e.style.display="none")
    document.getElementById(elementId).style.display="block";
}
```

```html
//button section
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-4 col-sm-2 col-lg-2">
      <div class="mx-2"><a id="me1" class="trans-btn selected" onclick="show('id1');">Widget</a></div>
      <div class="mx-2"><a id="me2" class="trans-btn" onclick="show('id2');">Widget</a></div>
      <div class="mx-2"><a id="me3" class="trans-btn" onclick="show('id3');">Widget</a></div>
   </div>
//1st 3 divs
   <div class="col-8 col-sm-5 col-lg-5">
      <div class="mx-2 myBlock" id="id1">
         <h3>Tabs with soft transitioning effect.</h3>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod 
            bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor sit amet lacus accumsan et viverra 
            justo commodo. Proin sodales pulvinar tempor. Cum sociis natoque 
            penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes.
         </p>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod 
            bibendum laoreet.
         </p>
         <a class="btn-warning" href="">Download</a>
      </div>
      <div class="mx-2 myBlock" id="id2" style="display:none;">
         <h3>Tabs Different effect.</h3>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod 
            bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor sit amet lacus accumsan et viverra 
            justo commodo. Proin sodales pulvinar tempor. Cum sociis natoque 
            penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes.
         </p>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod 
            bibendum laoreet.
         </p>
         <a class="btn-warning" href="">Download</a>
      </div>
      <div class="mx-2 myBlock" id="id3" style="display:none;">
         <h3>Tabs most of effect.</h3>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod 
            bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor sit amet lacus accumsan et viverra 
            justo commodo. Proin sodales pulvinar tempor. Cum sociis natoque 
            penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes.
         </p>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod 
            bibendum laoreet.
         </p>
         <a class="btn-warning" href="">Download</a>
      </div>
   </div>

//next 3 divs(image section)
   <div class="col-12 col-sm-5 col-lg-5 last-sec">
      <div class="mx-2" id="id1"><img class="img-fluid" src="assets/images/shadow-img.png"/></div>
      <div class="mx-2" id="id2" style="display:none;"><img class="img-fluid" src="assets/images/shadow-img.png"/></div>
      <div class="mx-2" id="id3" style="display:none;"><img class="img-fluid" src="assets/images/shadow-img.png"/></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `document.getElementById()` will gives you the first matched element, so you will be changing the first matched element's style only, not the second one.

You can consider changing the id attribute with a class, as the id attribute is meant to be unique.

```
// remove the id attribute if it's not used in other places
// class-replacement-for-id1 here is just a placeholder, it can be anything you want
<div class="mx-2 class-replacement-for-id1" id="id1">

<div class="mx-2 class-replacement-for-id1" id="id1">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/images/shadow-img.png"/>
</div>
```

And then use `document.querySelectorAll('.class-replacement-for-id1')` to select the elements

```
function toggleDisplay(className) { 
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.' + className);

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.display = elements[i].style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
}
```